# Vue and rails: Share cookie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, webpacker

I have a Rails 5.2 app with webpacker and Vue. My Rails app is using devise for authentication. I'm doing the following:

```
fetch("/search?q=" + this.q)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function() {

  });
```

which hits the right controller. However, the request gets redirected due to `before_action :authenticate_user!` in my Search controller.

I could implement JWT or some kind of authentication between the frontend and backend, but is there not a way to share a cookie in development? Unless I'm mistaken, when webpacker is in production, the code will get bundled inside my rails app, and then there wouldn't be a need for JWT.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to build a public api. I'm just trying to use Vue to build a search feature on my app.

Comment: Maybe you could retrieve the existing cookies with js-cookie and pass it along with the fetch?

Comment: @Ruslan,Oh yeah that was the issue. WHy does fetch do that? If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` does not send cookies by default.

You need to include credentials:

```
fetch("/search?q=" + this.q, {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```